How to spawn object Using Black & White image in specific order
See Black and White Image
by using this image, I am spawning object in 3D.
Logic is simple
White Pixel > Spawn Object.
Black Pixel > Do Nothing.
this thing is working fine. But I want to spawn Object in Specific Order.
See this image for Specific order
Here is my code for Read pixel data from image and spawn object according to it.
but I don`t to know How to traverse image pixels in specific order or path, because currently my code is reading pixels from bottom to top.
using Dreamteck.Splines;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ReadImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D spawnMap; // Assign your black and white image in the inspector
    public float spawnSpacing = 1.0f; // Space between spawned objects in world units
    public Vector2 startPosition = Vector2.zero; // World position where the spawning starts
    public bool canSpawn;

    [SerializeField] GameObject cubePrefab;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (canSpawn)
        {
            SpawnObjects();
        }
    }

    void SpawnObjects()
    {
        int index = 0;
        // Loop through each pixel in the image
        for (int x = 0; x < spawnMap.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < spawnMap.height; y++)
            {
                // Get the pixel color at (x, y)
                Color pixelColor = spawnMap.GetPixel(x, y);
                
                // Check if the pixel is white (you can also use a tolerance)
                if (pixelColor == Color.white)
                {
                    // Convert pixel position to world position
                    Vector3 worldPos = new Vector3(x * spawnSpacing, 0, y * spawnSpacing);
                    index++;
                    // Spawn the object at the calculated world position
                    Instantiate(cubePrefab,worldPos,Quaternion.identity,transform);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Guys, please suggest idea or method to achieve this.

Is the order specific to this one pattern? Then I'd hardcode it and be done ^^ Otherwise, for any arbitrary pattern .. how would you in your head decide what the order should be...? Should it always be an outline? This might be a start point then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453156/outline-plotting-algorithm

If you need a specific order, you could encode it into e.g. one of the channels and sort the points by that channel.

No, there is 50 - 60 images, each image will have own order. we can`t hardcode for each image. although we can change something in image to get "specific order".

How, can you explain more? encode channel or sort the points by that channel?

Find all non-black pixels, sort them by one channel's value. You'll of course need to craft the 50-60 images so they do have that order in the channel.

of course you could hand code them, if you can draw a picture with dots, store the order the dots and positions are placed, so, like (0,10), (5,10),(5,15),(15,15)....

Why can't you hardcode for each image? Just because there are too many images?
